# List into Integer (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, python-sockets

```
port = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 80]
s.connect((host, port))
```

The error I get is that an integer is required, how can i get the script to connect to the given ports?

Comment: ...One at a time.

Comment: What type is `s`?

Comment: If it is a socket, what do you expect to happen when it connects to multiple ports? Or did you want to have multiple sockets, one per port? Please explain...

Comment: Sorry, s = socket and I want the script to connect to all the given ports one after another.(So first 21 than 22 than 23, etc.)